# How to extract some data from a collection using lambda/linq to objects?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-to-objects

i have an `IList<Animals> farmAnimals;`

this list has three types,

- Cows
- Sheep
- Chickens

how can i remove all the Chickens from the list using a *lambda query* or *linq-to-objects* so i have a separate list of chickens and the original list now only has cows and sheep.

Do i have to make three lists (the original + 2 new ones, filtered) and then null the original list? or is there a trickier way?

result needs to be

```
IList<Aniamls> chickens;
IList<Animals> farmAnimals; // only contains the cows and sheep, now.
```

cheers!

### CLARIFICATION QUESTION:

what is more performant? FindAll & RemoveAll versus the Where suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
public abstract class Animal {}

public class Chicken : Animal {}
```

you can do:

```
var chickens = animals.OfType<Chicken>().Cast<Animal>().ToList();

var nonChickens = animals.Except(chickens).ToList();
```

**Edit**

Any reasonable answer should be [O(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), meaning each item in the original list is only processed once. Therefore, I would suggest an imperative approach:

```
var chickens = new List<Animal>();
var nonChickens = new List<Animal>();

foreach(var animal in animals)
{
    var list = animal is Chicken ? chickens : nonChickens;

    list.Add(animal);
}
```

Comment: are there any performance differences between Except vs RemoveAll and OfType+Cast vs FindAll ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var chickens = farmAnimals.ToList().FindAll (c => c.Type == "Chicken");
farmAnimals.RemoveAll(a => a.Type=="Chicken");
```

Comment: Doesn't RemoveAll returns an int? is that the number of items LEFT or REMOVED? i also prefer 'is' over .Type == 'blah'.

Comment: Actually RemoveAll does not return a collection, it returns the number of items removed.

Comment: hmm,
c is your Animal class
c.Type is Animal.Type

is this what did you ask ?

Comment: nope. c => c is Chicken is correct, becuase Chicken : Animal (chicken inherits animal).

Comment: sorry about RemoveAll, my fault

Comment: This will process the original sequence 3 times, once for each ToList() and once for the RemoveAll(). Linq is not the best solution; since you needs 2 lists in the end, you should use an imperative approach.

Comment: is there any performance loss while doing farmAnimals.ToList()

i mean is it casting IList to List ? doing some kind of casting inside a loop ?

Comment: The performance loss is that you are processing the original sequence multiple times: the first ToList(), the FindAll(), the second ToList(), and the RemoveAll(). See my answer for an imperative approach which processes "farmAnimals" only once.

Answer (score 2):

```
var chickens = farmAnimals.Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(Chicken)).ToList();
farmAnimals = farmAnimals.Where(a => a.GetType() != typeof(Chicken)).ToList();
```

Comment: interesting use of Where. maybe replace the typeof checks with an 'is' check.

Answer (score 0):

var Chickens = farmAnimals.FindAll(a=>a is Chicken);

I have a terrible tendency to sway to the simplest solution possible. In this case, using the lambda only requires the .NET framework 2.0. The LINQ extension methods require 3.5.

Comment: I think you need C# 3.0 for Lambdas, not 2.0.

Comment: Correct, Language Specification 3.0 - but it will compile and run on Framework 2.0 and does not require Framework 3 or 3.5.